# radgrid cell editable

Tags: asp.net, ajax, grid, tooltip, edit

Please can anyone give me solution.
Here is the problem.
Am passing a datatable as datasourse to a rad grid. The coumns of datatable are autogenerated depending on the data. So, I did nt added the itemtemplates for the rad grid. in the aspx page. 
How i should make each cell as editable as well I want give rad tool tip for every cell.

Please help me in this problem

Regards,
Bharath

Answer (score 0):

To make the grid cells editable, simply add EditCommandColumn in the grid (either auto-generated or declarative). To add tooltips, use [this approach](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-appearance-tooltips-for-grid-items.html) and include RadToolTipManager on the page with AutoTooltipify property set to true.